Why does PyQGIS start saying roo.children() is empty after a while?
I am working on a small extension to the QgsProject Class.
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.34.6/apps/qgis-ltr/python")
from qgis.core import (QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsLayerTreeGroup, QgsLayerTreeLayer)
import numpy as np

qgs = QgsApplication([],False)

qgs.initQgis()

class ExtQgsProject(QgsProject):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
            cls._instance.__initialized = False
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.__initialized:
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.layers = {}
            self.root = self.layerTreeRoot()
            self.__initialized = True

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = cls()
        return cls._instance

    def compile_layers(self, group=None):
        if group is None:
            group = self.root
        for child in group.children():
            if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                self.compile_layers(child)
            elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
                layer = child.layer()
                self.layers[layer.name()] = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()

project = ExtQgsProject.instance()
project.read("Path/ExampleProject.qgz")
project.compile_layers()
print(project.layers)

qgs.exitQgis()

I would like for the method compile_layers to populate the self.layers dictionary with layers[layer_name] = layer_path for each layer in the project. If I open the QGIS Project in the QGIS application then run the program it works well. However, after some time (~5minutes) I run the program again and ... the dictionary is empty. To get the program to work again I have to restart QGIS, reopen the project and restart the kernel. Why is this?
